# connection between eigenvalues of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given 2 matrices $A_1 $ and $A_2$

$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -3 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 5 \\
1&1&-1 
\end{pmatrix} 
 $$
$$ A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3 & 4\\
4&6&-5 \\
1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I was asked to calculate the eigenvalues of each of these matrices which I found to be $\lambda_1 = 0 $ for $A_1$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$ for $A_2$

I was then asked to identify the connection between the 2 matrices which I have said $A_1 = (A_2 - 2I)$, however the second part of this question asks:
*Does the connection explain the connection between the eigenvalues of $A_1$ & $A_2$?*

I'm not certain about what would be deemed a sufficient answer to this question, would it be enough to mention that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 - 2 $ ?

Comment: You can easily prove that assertion by considering the eigenvectors. Pick for example one eigenvector of $A_1$ and look what happens if you multiply this eigenvector with $A_2$. Do you see what happens? Moreover, can you explain why?

Comment: @Rito Lowe The answer for your question is in fact it depends on whether there exists a similarity transformation between the two implying $A_1\equiv A_2$. For which assume $B_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Do they have relation just because eigen values are the same? can we transform from $B_1$ to $B_2$, and vice-versa?

Comment: I believe there are some typos in your question as $A_{1}\neq A_{2}-2I$. As to answering that question, you probably use the fact that in finite dimensions $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ if it is in the the kernel of $A-\lambda I$.